# Does an economics degree qualify for the 17 month OPT extension?

Tags: visa

(This question is about US work authorization for foreign students.)

The [list of STEM fields](http://www.ice.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Document/2014/stem-list.pdf) which will permit one to get a 17 month OPT extension include only two fields that containing the word "economics".

- 45.0603 Econometrics and Quantitative Economics
- 51.2007 Pharmacoeconomics/Pharmaceutical Economics

The latter is definitely not applicable to me, so I am interested only in the former.

According to [this page](https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/cipcode/cipdetail.aspx?y=55&cip=45.0603), "45.0603 Econometrics and Quantitative Economics" is defined to be

> A program that focuses on the systematic study of mathematical and statistical analysis of economic phenomena and problems. Includes instruction in economic statistics, optimization theory, cost/benefit analysis, price theory, economic modeling, and economic forecasting and evaluation.

My question is: If my diploma says simply that I have a degree in economics (as is often the case with degrees in economics), would I automatically qualify for the 17 month OPT extension? If not, is there any way I could go about proving that I satisfy the above definition? (It seems to me that any decent degree in economics would arguably satisfy the above definition.)

Comment: I have voted to close as off-topic as this question is asking for legal advice.

Comment: Words like "automatic" are very uncertain concepts when they come to US immigration law: I think you really need to talk to a lawyer or to the foreign students office at your institution (who have lawyers to consult with).

Comment: **ANSWER**: Look at page 3 of your I-20. Near the top there is an item "Primary Major". You are eligible for the 17-month STEM extension if and only If the code listed there appears on the ICE's list of STEM fields.

Comment: Note though that I-20 forms issued from July 2015 onwards will look slightly different and the information will appear instead on page 1. [Sample of I-20 form from July 2015 onwards](http://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/Form%20I-20%20SAMPLE.pdf).

Comment: I do not understand why those who know nothing about this matter simply presumed that there could not be a definite, general answer to this question, and were so eager to vote to close. It turns out that there *is* a definite, general answer that will be useful to the many thousands of non-US economics graduates in the US every year.

Comment: @Kenny LJ, If you add your answer (maybe include links to the ICE list, etc. and rewrite the question to be something like: Is my major is eligible for the 17-month STEM OPT extension?, the question could be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

CIP codes in economics include:

45.0601) Economics, General.

45.0602) Applied Economics.

45.0603) Econometrics and Quantitative Economics.

45.0604) Development Economics and International Development.

45.0605) International Economics.

45.0699) Economics, Other.

Your registrar's office should be able to tell you what the CIP code is for the degree program that you're in.  I would expect the list that you have referenced to include other codes if they were approved for OPT.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign student's office at your university is responsible for your OPT application and the accompanying paperwork.

They are the best place to ask not only because they're doing the paperwork and would know of previous successful applications, but also because they have the discretion to make the application based on their knowledge of your university's economics program and your particular course of study.

Note that even if your university agrees with your argument and puts it forward, the USCIS also has the discretion to disagree and reject it, falling back to the standard OPT.